# Using dB to measure acceptable volume level

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I am designing a system that accesses a user's webcam and want to check if the audio level is good (not very loud or very low). I was thinking of testing it on several videos and myself to find an acceptable dB range and use that as threshold values for the system. Does it make sense to try this using dB as a measurement, especially when I wouldn't know the hardware the user is using to record audio? I don't plan on doing this in real-time but instead recording a short clip of the user speaking and analyzing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of measuring "loudness".

The PCM sample values you're going to get in your software are effectively instantaneous measurements of a signal, in floating point.  They will have a range between `-1.0` and `+1.0`.  (It is not possible to determine the actual sound pressure decibels in the room without some calibration.)

Just because a sample value is as high as `1.0` or `-1.0` doesn't necessarily mean you have a "loud" sound!  If it blips up there for a sample or two, and immediately stops, you have a fairly quiet-sounding click.  Measuring the maximum absolute value gives you a peak value which often correlates with loudness, but it isn't quite the same thing.

There are several standards for figuring out loudness.  Sounds like you want to implement your own, but you might use an existing standard to start your research.  See also:  https://www.tcelectronic.com/brand/tcelectronic/loudness-explained

Comment: I don't think it's quite right to be equating instantaneous sample values -1.0 to 1.0 with dB.

Comment: @jaket How's that?  Would you not say that either `-1.0` or `+1.0` are 0 dBFS?  Happy to correct and/or clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: 20*log10(-1) is -infinity.  dBFS is specifically defined such that the RMS amplitude of a full scale sine (-1 to 1) is 0 dBFS.  The RMS amplitude of a full scale square wave is +3 dBFS.  I guess what I'm trying to say is that any loudness types of measures I'm aware of, including RMS, involve some integration over time and that makes the last sentence of the first full paragraph a bit confusing.  Cheers

Comment: @jaket Yeah, totally agreed on loudness, I was referring to the peak signal level.  I will clean up this answer to clarify.  Thank you for your comments.